# What's the difference between OnListItemClick vs onItemClickListener

Tags: android, listadapter

I can't figure out which to use. I am trying to make it so that when you click on an item on the list view adapter, it will delete the item. Which one should I use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The listener is an interface and the other is the method you implement for that interface. You'll also need setOnItemClickListener().

Comment: so do I put both in the code? Like `onListItemClick` and `onItemClick` ?

Comment: Yes. Please see  http://www.ezzylearning.com/tutorial/handling-android-listview-onitemclick-event